# Android write a file that shows in Downloads app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have my app export a .csv file that can be picked up in the download APP.  The way I am doing this is through fileoutput

I get remotedir By calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

```
 * Download CSV
 */
public static void downloadCSV(String filename, String remoteDir) throws Exception{
    File dir = new File( remoteDir + "/download/");

    dir.mkdirs();

    //FileWriter f = new FileWriter("Download/" + filename + ".csv");
    File fileObject = new File(dir, filename);
    fileObject.delete();
    fileObject.createNewFile();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = null;
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fileObject);
    objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(stream));


    /* Irrelevant code */

    String csv = Helper.getCSV(table.getColumnList(), view);
    objectOut.writeChars(csv);
    objectOut.close();
}
```

Whenever I test it on my phone(HTC One S) I don't see the file anywhere.  I want my csv file to pop up in the Downloads app, but I'm not sure which directory that represents.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have to scan the file with the MediaScanner before it will show up, at least that's how you'll be able to see it from your desktop for finding/debugging.  See the [MediaScanner docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for details.